# Twitter API : Error "The validation of media ids failed." in update.json

Tags: image, api, rest, twitter, upload

I just want to post status with images with the twitter api and their not deprecated method:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json.

Before this, i successfuly upload my image with https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json, and i get my media_id.

Then, using the https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console, i just use the update.json method, with the parameter status, and i add the parameter "media_ids", and put the media_id i received when i upload the image.

The response is a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`,

```
"errors":  [
     {
      "code": 324,
      "message": "The validation of media ids failed."
    }
  ]
```

How can i upload multiple images using the api? After i success i want to do it via Twitterizer in c#, but first im trying to make it works in the rest console.

Thanks